# Вызов статического метода для наследников интерфейса

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Есть базовый интерфейс, который имеет список корректных имен.

```
class Base 
{
public:
   // метод для получения данных из списка
   static QString get_valid_coin_name(const QString &coin)
   {
       return (m_valid_pair_list.contains(coin)) ? m_valid_pair_list.value(coin) : coin;
   }

protected:
   QHash <QString, QString> m_valid_pair_list; // список
   int id;
}
```

Так же есть несколько наследников этого класса, которые хранят в этом списке свои данные.

```
class FirstDerived : public Base 
{
   // ...
   m_valid_pair_list.insert("invalid1", "valid1");
   id = 1;
}

class SecondDerived : public Base 
{
   // ...
   m_valid_pair_list.insert("invalid2", "valid2");
   id = 2;
}
```

В программе по `id` я получаю указатель на реализацию интерфейса. Но в таком случае вызывается конструктор наследника.

```
Base* get_derived(const int & id) {
   // опустил switch по id
   static Derived derived;
   return derived;
}
```

Необходимо не создавая наследника, обратиться к списку и получить из него данные. Если метод и поле статические, можно сделать. Однако, я не смог разобраться, как мне получить доступ к нужной реализации наследника без создания объекта.

В итоге должно получится что-то вроде такого:

```
get_derived(id)::get_valid_coin_name(coin);
```

Comment: Код полностью не рабочий. Сначала изучите `static` - в языке, затем используйте. Определение статического метода  в классе - даёт доступ к данным объекта, но чтобы был фактически к ним доступ нужно в методе задавать аргумент с ссылкой на конкретный объект, у которого вы хотите взять данные. Статическое объявление переменной в методе создаёт объект при запуске программы один раз. Не понятно, что вы хотите добиться от программы. Доступнее пожалуйста объясните.

Comment: @AlexGlebe если в двух словах, я хочу инкапсулировать инициализацию переменной для каждого наследника. Чтобы каждый наследник хранил только свои данные. Логика работы с этими данными одинакова для всех, поэтому вынесена в статический метод родителя. В программе нужно обратиться к данным наследника по id. Т.е. id = 2, обращаемся к наследнику SecondDerived и берем из него данные. Использую ``static`` из тех соображений, что нет смысла иницализировать весь объект ради одной переменной, которая не будет изменяться.

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к полю `m_valid_pair_list` необходимо инициализировать весь объект, а функция должна быть не `static` Как вы собираетесь обращаться к полю объекта не создавая его?

Comment: Может быть просто сделать список `m_valid_pair_list` - статическим?

Comment: @AlexGlebe объявив ``m_valid_pair_list`` статически в родительском классе он станет глобальным для всех наследников. Верно? Каким образом можно будет его инкапсулировать для каждого наследника отдельно? После этого, как обратиться к ``m_valid_pair_list`` конкретного наследника, используя абстрактную фабрику (пример выше ``get_derived``)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо, чтобы у каждого экземпляра каждого наследного класса были отдельный списки, то так вы и сделали. Но вы хотите, не использовать никакой экземпляр?

Значит вам нужно **отдельный** статический список? Тогда никаких указателей вам не надо возвращать. А только работать по номеру/типу класса. Используя `switch`.

```
class Ba{
public:
static QString get_valid_coin_name(int t,const QString &coin);
};

class Fi:public Ba{
static std::list<std::pair<QString,QString>> list;
};

class Se:public Ba{
static std::list<std::pair<QString,QString>> list;
};

enum{TFi,TSe};

QString Ba::get_valid_coin_name(int t,const QString &coin)   {
switch(t){
case TFi:
       return (Fi::list.contains(coin)) ? Fi::list.value(coin) : coin;
case TSe:
       return (Se::list.contains(coin)) ? Se::list.value(coin) : coin;
default: return "ошибка";}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, Вы все слишком переусложнили, пытались использовать наследование, там где оно не нужно. Вот мое решение Вашей задачи.

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QHash>
#include <QDebug>

class Base
{
public:
    static QString get_valid_coin_name(int _id, const QString &coin)
    {
        static QMap<int, Base> data = baseInit();

        return data[_id].m_valid_pair_list.contains(coin) ?
                    data[_id].m_valid_pair_list.value(coin) :
                    coin;
    }
private:
   QHash <QString, QString> m_valid_pair_list; // список

   static QMap<int, Base> baseInit()
   {
        QMap<int, Base> out;

        {
            Base item;
            item.m_valid_pair_list.insert("invalid1", "valid1");
            out[1] = item;
        }

        {
            Base item;
            item.m_valid_pair_list.insert("invalid2", "valid2");
            out[2] = item;
        }

        return out;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << Base::get_valid_coin_name(1, "invalid1");
    qDebug() << Base::get_valid_coin_name(2, "invalid2");

    return 0;
}
```

Метод `baseInit` будет вызван только один раз, при первом выполнение функции `get_valid_coin_name`.